# Adding another variable to an array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-deployment

So im editing some code and I would like to add another variable to an array. The code below works perfectly:

```
submit.addAttributeValue = function() {
    var aValue = submit.status.newAttributeValue;
    var aType = submit.status.selectedAttributeType;
    console.log('adding value', aValue, aType)
    if(aValue && aType ) {
        submit.ProductMeta['attributes'][aType][aValue] = true;
    };
};
```

I then add the variable aPrice to the function:

```
submit.addAttributeValue = function() {
    var aValue = submit.status.newAttributeValue;
    var aType = submit.status.selectedAttributeType;
    var aPrice = submit.status.newAttributePrice;
    console.log('adding value', aValue, aType, aPrice)
    if(aValue && aType ) {
        submit.ProductMeta['attributes'][aType][aValue][aPrice] = true;
    };
};
```

I get the error:

`Error: submit.ProductMeta.attributes[aType][aValue] is undefined
submit.addAttributeValue@http://dubdelivery.com/js/controllers-submit.js:369:13`

ProductMeta is defined as: `submit.ProductMeta = {};`

Any advice on how I should approach this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is empty so you can't set a second level field before the first

If you have

```
var obj = {};
```

You have to set

```
obj.firstItem
```

before

```
obj.firstItem.secondItem
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11413/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the debugger or just console log "aType", "aValue", and "aPrice". I'm betting "aValue" is undefined.

If you're going to go about manipulating object properties this way, you have to make sure the variables that contain your property names actually have values.

(BTW, especially now with ES6 classes, you probably shouldn't be manipulating object property/values this way).